# Why Magento 2 have 2 possible root folder?

Tags: magento2, index

I'm trying to figure out how **Magento 2** is working. I've seen something that made me confuse.

**Magento 2** have 2 **possible** root folder:

```
/path/to/magento2/index.php
/path/to/magento2/pub/index.php
```

One is at the absolute top level of Magento 2’s distribution folder. The second is inside the “pub” folder.

If I set base URL is either of them, magento is working perfectly.

Can anyone explain me why Magento 2 using 2 root folder like that ?

Comment: i like when root folder is `/pub/`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using `/pub` is better, because it is more secure. Why? Because in that case most of Magento's code will live outside the public document root, so the possible attack surface is smaller. In other words, when you use the top level folder as document root, you have to make sure that various folders (such as `app`) are explicitly denied in your webserver configuration.

That said, not everybody can configure the document root, so Magento provided a top level `index.php` for compatibility.

Comment: Best answer short explained. +1

Answer (score 1):

Main reason that no all Magento Users can configure webroot to the "pub" directory. 
And of course due to  backward compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use /pub folder as root be ready to have a problems with robots.txt and sitemap.xml.

More info: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/1146