# Two entry point: index.php and pub/index.php

Tags: index.php

I am facing the problem of having two entry points to Magento2 `index.php` and `pub/index.php`.

I want to add another DIR called "pub", add this to the document root load and test it.

**Currently it is:**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\
```

But I want to set it to:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\pub\
```

What are the correct steps to point apache to the correct entry point and load the necessary files?

Comment: May be https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103814/what-is-the-benefit-of-a-pub-directory-in-magento-2 and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98558/why-magento-2-have-2-possible-root-folder will help you.

Comment: Thank you - but these threads do not answer how to make sure the Magento docroot is set to the pub directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use only one you can set in the "httpd.conf" the Documentroot must be at row: 183 
Path to the httpd.conf is:

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
```

change to: `DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\pub`
After change restart the apache.

Comment: That works. Do I need to copy any files from: C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\ to C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\pub\. My storefronts are not the same.

Comment: Yes you must copy all Files in the root folder in you case magento2/pub